# How images in flat design websites are created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, screenshot, flat-design

First, I would like to know if the images in this [portfolio](http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/website-templates/) **screenshots**?

Then, are the images in [this web page](http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/website-templates/responsive-bootstrap-theme-for-mobile-apps-delta/) screenshots of the [website](http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/delta/1.9.2/)? Otherwise, how did the designer draw these images?

In the end, the image in the following website is certainly NOT screenshot, how were they drawn in general? The designer needed to draw every detail?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I would like to know if the images in this portfolio
>   screenshots?

I don't think we can know for certain but my guess would be yes they are screenshots. Since that site is selling templates I am guessing the screen shots are of the actual template website and not just a mockup. But the creator could have made that in a image editing program.

> Then, are the images in this web page screenshots of the website?
>   Otherwise, how did the designer draw these images?

Yes they would have needed to draw every detail (unless they used some pre-made objects). The above image is a lot of copy paste shapes. For the laptop the designer would create the website look in a 2D plane and then distort the objects to match the laptop perspective.

> how were they drawn in general? The designer needed to draw every
>   detail?

Using various tools and text in most likely a vector editing program. It may look like a lot at first but when you closely inspect the graphics you will notice a lot of repeating objects. So someone isn't manually placing each shape as there are functions to copy paste objects at specific distances from each other.

There are also a lot of already made product mockups for stock use that a designer could have used.

---

I re-made the tablet shown in your picture in about 5 minutes (I didn't do everything but you get the idea). It would probably take a little bit longer to make if I wasn't copying a design and had to think of what to create.

[image: Tablet mockup]

Comment: For the second question, "The above image is a lot of copy paste shapes." ==> where did the very basic shapes come from? Nothing was from screenshot of the working website?

Comment: @SoftTimur the designer would draw them with a rectangular shape tool. They are not from an actual website.

Comment: What software did you use to make the picture on the right hand side?

Comment: @SoftTimur in Adobe Illustrator but the same could be made in other vector programs like Inkscape or Sketch. They could even be made in a pixel editing program like Photoshop or GIMP.